# Ions in different cell compartments

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I would like to understand the distribution of metal ion concentrations (such as Mg2+) in the different cell compartments. I tried very hard but still couldn't find such information. Could anyone help?  Also, could you recommend a good reference on this problem? Thank you!